# Remove IWebElement from IList<IWebElement> based on text in IWebElement

Tags: c#, selenium

I retrieve a list of elements from a page using:

```
var elements = Driver.FindElements(locator)
```

I want to remove all the list items in elements that contain a particular text attribute "testing"

I believe it will be something like:

```
var elements = Driver.FindElements(locator).Remove(...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RemoveAll` with a lambda expression to remove all the elements with matching text

```
elements.RemoveAll(el => el.Text == "testing");
```